# Remove a element from a collection in mongodb if the key has a value in its array

Tags: mongodb

How do i remove this element from my mongodb collection called fruits.
In the given collection I want expression to remove first element since it contains "orange" as a element in "tag".

```
{"_id":ObjectId("dedrfrcece"), "tags":["apple", "orange"]}
{"_id":ObjectId("afedfrcece"), "tags":["apple", "banana"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to delete all documents that contains an "orange" element in their "tags" array.

```
db.fruits.remove( { tags: "orange"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [the "$pull" operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

Here's a full example (I chose the lowercase property name "tags" in order to be in line with your example without the need for any custom mapping):

```
public class Test
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Test>("Test");

        collection.InsertMany(new[] { new Test { tags = new[] { "apple", "orange" } } });
        collection.InsertMany(new[] { new Test { tags = new[] { "apple", "banana" } } });

        collection.UpdateMany(Builders<Test>.Filter.Empty, Builders<Test>.Update.Pull(test => test.tags, "orange"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```